Visual Studio Code selection highlight border color is not applied consistently
I have set a customized editor selection highlight border color in VS Code. So when I double click on some text in my code, other occurrences of that text are highlighted and they display a border with my customized color which makes them easier to spot.
However, in some cases the highlight border is not the color I specified - it is fainter. If anything, I would actually like the occurrences in comments to not have as much attention drawn to them, or at least for all occurrences to have the same border color, but this is not what I'm seeing. I am hoping there is another color setting in VS Code that can help with this. The image shows what I'm currently seeing.

I tried modifying settings.json as such:
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionHighlightBorder" :"#f38518",
    },

It worked, but I'm guessing there is another color setting for certain kinds of highlighted text that is interfering with this setting.
